# Android Preference - replace preference function

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have an `EditPreference` in a `PreferenceActivity` and I have a variable that tells me if I should allow the user to access this preference or to show some alert.

My problem is that I couldn't find how to cancel the preference dialog before it's displayed and to show my alert (according to the variable).

I tried to return true/false in the preference `onClick` or in `onTreeClick` but that didn't do anything, the dialog still popped.

On Android 2.1+ .

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`DialogPreference.onClick()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/DialogPreference.html#onClick%28%29), which handles clicks to the preference itself, is `protected`, so you can't override it in your own `PreferenceActivity` class members.

However, you can extend the class to achieve what you need. Below is a very minimalist example:

```
package com.example.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.preference.EditTextPreference;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class MyEditTextPreference extends EditTextPreference {

    private Runnable alternative = null;

    public MyDatePickerDialog(Context context, 
            AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public MyDatePickerDialog(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyDatePickerDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void setAlternativeRunnable(Runnable runnable) {
        alternative = runnable;
    }

    // this will probably handle your needs
    @Override
    protected void onClick() {
        if (alternative == null) super.onClick();
        else alternative.run();
    }

}
```

In your XML file:

```
<com.example.test.MyEditTextPreference
        android:key="myCustom"
        android:title="Click me!" />
```

In your `PreferenceActivity`:

```
MyEditTextPreference pref = (MyEditTextPreference) this.findPreference("myCustom");
pref.setAlternativeRunnable(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Canceled!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
});
```

**As a final note**, let me say that whenever you can't find a way to do what you want, think about taking a look at how the Android classes themselves work. Most of the times, they will give you good insights to achieve what you want.

In this case, it's the [`DialogInterface.onClick()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/DialogPreference.html#onClick%28%29) method, as described above. So you know you need to override it somehow to achieve that. In this case, the solution is extending the `EditTextPreference` class itself.

Comment: btw, you can definitely improve that with flags etc. This is just an example.